# Why running yarn commands is giving an error- Integrity check failed for "yargs-parser"

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm, installation, yarnpkg

**The problem-**

In my existing Vue project if I am running the `yarn install` or `yarn add package_name` command, the following errors are occurring-

[image]

[image]

**What I read-**

After reading [this article](https://www.arahansen.com/the-ultimate-guide-to-yarn-lock-lockfiles/) (scroll down to the "Integrity Hash" section), I was able to achieve some understanding about this error that-

> yarn will compute a hash value for each dependency install based on
> the contents that were downloaded. Next time you download that
> dependency, yarn generates the hash again.
> If there is a mismatch between the new value and the value stored in yarn.lock, yarn will throw an error that looks like this: `Integrity check failed for <package-name> (computed integrity doesn't match our records, got <integrity-hash-value>`)

I believe my error is related. The solution also suggested in [this article](https://www.arahansen.com/the-ultimate-guide-to-yarn-lock-lockfiles/) is to read about the culprit dependency and if it's safe to use, re-install this. I also read this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/yargs/yargs-parser/issues/270).

**My concern-**

As far as I read, **once a resolved version is specified in `yarn.lock` that will always be the version installed whenever you run `yarn install`.** In my `yarn.lock` the version of `yargs-parser` is `20.2.1`.

Should I re-install this `yargs-parser` dependency, if yes, then how? I am kind of worried about the re-installation impact on other dependencies.

**My environment details-**

The following package managers are installed globally in my system-

```
node- 14.19.0
yarn- 1.22.4
npm- 6.14.16
```

I can provide further details if needed. Any help would do great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, after a few days of research, I finally sort out this problem.

### Cause for this error-

As I cited in the question about my suspicion of integrity mismatch, was right.

***Integrity checksums are a security feature used by Yarn to ensure that the contents of a package have not been tampered with since they were published to the registry. So, when you install a package, Yarn downloads the package's tarball from the registry and verifies that the integrity checksum matches the one listed in the `yarn.lock` file.***

And in my case, the hashes didn't match somehow and that was the reason in actuality.

### What I tested-

1. Cleared the yarn cache. (very basic, didn't work though)
2. Deleted the `yarn.lock` and installed it again. (very destructive results because it potentially updates all packages when you really just have an issue with the single package.)
3. Thought to re-install only this `yargs-parser` package but it's not possible because it is not added in the `package.json` file. :-(

## What truly fixed the issue

**The hero command-**

```
yarn --update-checksums
```

**What does this command do?**

If the integrity checksum of any package is out of date or incorrect then running this command will regenerate them based on the current content of the registry.

So this command corrected the hash of my `yargs-parser` package and now I am able to use yarn commands perfectly.

I am open to any other thoughts on this concept.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the yarn.lock file and running `yarn install` again

Answer (score 0):

This answer is very old. These commands are no longer valid in the latest versions of yarn after v3 and above

current latest version - 4.1.0

I find these steps helpful in such situations -

1. Clean the cache and install.

```bash
yarn cache clean --all
```

2. Run update with `update-lockfile` mode.

```bash
yarn up --mode update-lockfile
```

3. Manually remove the entry of only the package causing problem from `yarn.lock` file and run `yarn install` or `yarn` again to repopulate the entries.
4. Extreme solution. Delete the lock file and install again.

```bash
rm yarn.lock
yarn
```